# How to change password in database when password is hashed already in database asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, passwords

hi my question is how to change the password when its already hashed and salt, i have web application asp.net C# and i want to make change password option in my website, but i cant change password in database if someone know to do it then please help or feel free to put forward for consideration link thanks in advance .

Here is my code

```
List<String> salthashlist = null;
        List<String> newlist = null;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            QueryStr = "select Password,UserName FROM UserData WHERE UserName= @uname";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Userlbl.Text);
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
            {
                if (salthashlist == null)
                {
                    salthashlist = new List<String>();
                    newlist = new List<String>();
                }
                String salHashes = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Password"));
                salthashlist.Add(salHashes);
                String fullname = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("UserName"));
                newlist.Add(fullname);
            }
            reader.Close();
            if (salthashlist != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < salthashlist.Count; i++)
                {
                    QueryStr = "";
                    bool validuser = PasswordHash.Validatepass(oldpasswordtxt.Text, salthashlist[i]);
                    if (validuser == true)
                    {
                        Session["New"] = newlist[i];
                        Response.BufferOutput = true;
                        String salthashreturned = PasswordHash.makehash(newpassconfirmtxt.Text);
                        int commaindex = salthashreturned.IndexOf(":");
                        String extractedstring = salthashreturned.Substring(0, commaindex);
                        commaindex = salthashreturned.IndexOf(":");
                        extractedstring = salthashreturned.Substring(commaindex + 1);
                        commaindex = extractedstring.IndexOf(":");
                        String salt = extractedstring.Substring(0, commaindex);
                        commaindex = extractedstring.IndexOf(":");
                        extractedstring = extractedstring.Substring(commaindex + 1);
                        String hash = extractedstring;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", salthashreturned);
                        passchangelbl.Text = "Your new password is changed successfully";
                        cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        passchangelbl.Text = "Please check your old password";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            passchangelbl.Text = "Please check your password" + ex;
        }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just salt and hash the new password and update the database with the result.

Comment: i did but its not working and its not even show the error

Comment: Please give a [mcve], we can't just guess what the problem is.

Comment: please see  my code

Comment: tell me the code is correct ? or may be i did some mistake

Comment: i am new to c# thats why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the new password to the database. You forgot to do that. You execute the incorrect `SELECT` command.

```
...
if (validuser == true)
{
    ...
    // error here:
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", salthashreturned);
    passchangelbl.Text = "Your new password is changed successfully";
    cmd.ExecuteReader();
    conn.Close();
}
```

You need to `UPDATE` the password hash in the database. Principle:

```
...
if (validuser == true)
{
    ...

    // possible solution in principle:
    cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE UserData SET Password=@newPassword WHERE UserName= @uname", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Userlbl.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPassword", salthashreturned);
    cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
    passchangelbl.Text = "Your new password is changed successfully";
}
```

Comment: i did before but still not working can you please show me how to correct it in proper way i am new in to c#

Comment: querystr i did that but the results is same

Comment: See update. It may work. If not it shows you a solution in principle at least.

Comment: still my code cant provide where is the error what should i do ?

Comment: are you talking about  QueryStr = "select Password,UserName FROM UserData WHERE UserName= @uname"; ?

Comment: @Apsdevs00698 Quality Catalyst's code shows how to UPDATE the database AFTER you run the query, right before the end of your function.

Comment: i got this error Please check your passwordSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@uname". at

Comment: @Apsdevs00698 First, your question was why you can't see an update in the DB. Answer: You need to update your DB. Second, my code sample is (only) working in principle: you need to update the DB correctly (!!) with and `UPDATE` instead of running a `SELECT`. As for your subsequent error: Have you added the `@uname` parameter to the command?

Comment: i don't know how to do it can you please  help me